# .bind(this) vs var context = this in Javascript - what's the best style?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, this

This is a style question, perhaps subjective.

Which is better to use for readable, standard code?

A: "var context = this"

```
var object = {
  foo: 'bar',
  method: function(){  
    var context = this;
    $.get('/some/async/api', function (req, res){
      console.log(context.foo);  //==> bar
    });
  }
}
```

B: ".bind(this)"

```
var object = {
  foo: 'bar',
  method: function(){  
    $.get('/some/async/api', (function (req, res){
      console.log(this.foo);  //==> bar
    }).bind(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: Context caching, you can use both the contexts

Comment: Seems like a question whose answers will be primarily opinion-based which is off-topic here.

Comment: Use arrow functions.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the 1st format as it's simple and efficient. [zone.js](https://github.com/btford/zone.js/) is a great library to use for scoping.